# jQuery обработчик click выполняется несколько раз при ajax запросе

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function get_answers(){
  $('#answers').load("{% url 'answers'  question.id%}");
  $( "#button" ).click (function() {
    console.log("click")
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{% url 'create_answer' question.id %}",
      data: $('#form').serialize(),
      success: function () {
        get_answers();
        $('#text').val("");
      },
    });
  });
}
```

Накапливается обработчик. Не пойму почему.
При обработке нажатия отправляются данные формы (добавление нового комментария), и в `<div id='answers'>` подгружаются все комментарии. Сама форма и кнопка на которую вешается обработчик в этот `div` не входит, и не загружается снова.  Если убрать ajax запрос, то `click` накапливаться не будет.

Comment: может потому что при удачном запросе вы повторно вызываете функцию `get_answers();`

Comment: регистрируете событие клик много раз по ходу

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk Точно! Вот я идиот. Не заметил что запрос находится внутри функции, что совершенно не нужно к тому же! Я не планировал его в внутри, поэтому даже не обратил внимания.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function get_answers(){
    //Бинд повесили 10 раз
    $( "#button" ).click (function() {
        console.log("click button")
    });
    
    //Бинд снимаем каждый раз перед тем как забиндить
    $( "#button2" ).unbind("click").click (function() {
        console.log("click button2")
    });
  
  
}

for(var i=0;i<=10;i++){
  get_answers();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button">11 выполнится </button>


<button id="button2">1 выполнится </button>
```

Снимай бинды лишние

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_answers(){
  $('#answers').load("{% url 'answers'  question.id%}");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#button" ).click (function() {
    console.log("click")
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{% url 'create_answer' question.id %}",
      data: $('#form').serialize(),
      success: function () {
        get_answers();
        $('#text').val("");
      },
    });
    return false;
  });
}
```